# Maintainability of Boolean logic - Is nesting if statements needed?

Tags: programming-practices, coding-standards, maintenance, readability

Which of these is better for maintainability?

```
if (byteArrayVariable != null)
    if (byteArrayVariable .Length != 0)
         //Do something with byteArrayVariable
```

OR

```
if ((byteArrayVariable != null) && (byteArrayVariable.Length != 0))
  //Do something with byteArrayVariable
```

I prefer reading and writing the second, but I recall reading in code complete that doing things like that is bad for maintainability.

This is because you are relying on the language to not evaluate the second part of the `if` if the first part is false and not all languages do that.  (The second part will throw an exception if evaluated with a null `byteArrayVariable`.)

I don't know if that is really something to worry about or not, and I would like general feedback on the question.

Thanks.

Comment: The first form has a risk of dangling-else's

Comment: just curious, what language are you working with?

Comment: @STW - we use C# and have some legacy code in Delphi.

Comment: good to know.  I'm not familiar with Delphi but in C# you can be confident in the `&&` and `||` operators performing short-circuit evaluation.  Going from one language to another usually has some gotchas, and it's good to be firm about doing code reviews to help catch those little issues.

Comment: While along with many answers here I find the second more readable, the first is far easier to debug. In this case, I'd still use the second because you're checking easy to debug things. But be careful in general.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think the second form is fine, and also more clearly represents what you're trying to do. You say that...

> I recall reading in code complete that doing things like that is bad for maintainability. This is because you are relying on the language to not evaluate the second part of the if if the first part is false and not all languages do that.

It doesn't matter if *all* languages do that. You're writing in *one* particular language, so it only matters if *that* language does that. Otherwise, you're essentially saying that you shouldn't use the features of a particular language because other languages might not support those features, and that's just silly.

Comment: Agreed. Why on earth would I care if my code will run the same when copied into another language?

Answer (score 16):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned it (so hopefully I'm not misreading the question)--**but both kind of suck!**

The better alternative would be to use early-exits (placing a return statement early in the code if no other code should execute).  This makes the assumption that your code is relatively well refactored, and that each method has a concise purpose.

At that point you would do something like:

```
if ((byteArrayVariable == null) || (byteArrayVariable.Length != 0)) {
  return; // nothing to be done, leaving
}

// Conditions met, do something
```

It might look a lot like validation--and that's precisely what it is.  It validates that conditions have been satisfied for the method to do it's thing--both options you offered hid the actual logic within the pre-condition checks.

If your code is a lot of spaghetti (loooong methods, lots of nested ifs with logic scattered between them, etc) then you should focus on the bigger problem of getting your code into shape before the smaller stylistic issues.  Depending on your environment, and the severity of the mess, there are some great tools to help (e.g. Visual Studio has an "Extract Method" refactoring function).

---

As Jim mentions, there's still room for debate about *how* to structure the early-exit.  The alternative to what is above would be:

```
if (byteArrayVariable == null) 
  return; // nothing to be done, leaving

if (byteArrayVariable.Length != 0)
  return;

// Conditions met, do something
```

Comment: I agree with the return instead of the wrapping of the good logic, but the same people will use the same argument about using || as for &&.

Answer (score 14):

Don't waste time trying to trap for every **non this** condition. If you can disqualify the data or condition then do so as soon as possible.

```
if (byteArrayVariable == null) Exit;
if (byteArrayVariable.Length == 0) Exit;
// do something
```

This lets you adapt your code much easier for new conditions

```
if (byteArrayVariable == null) Exit;
if (byteArrayVariable.Length == 0) Exit;
if (NewCondition == false) Exit;
if (NewerCondition == true) Exit;
// do something
```

Comment: +1 Yup, yup, yup. Logic as simple as this should not result in difficult code. Your (asker's) gut should be telling you this.

Answer (score 11):

Your example is the perfect example of why the nested `ifs` are a bad approach for most languages that properly support boolean comparison. Nesting the `ifs` creates a situation where your intention is not at all clear. Is it required that the second `if` immediately follows the first one? Or is it just because you haven't put another operation in there yet?

```
if ((byteArrayVariable != null) && (byteArrayVariable.Length != 0))
  //Do something with byteArrayVariable
```

In this case, these pretty much *must* be together. They are acting as a guard to ensure you don't perform an operation that would result in an exception. Using nested `ifs`, you leave it up to interpretation of the person following you as to whether the two represent a two-part guard or some other branching logic. By combining them into a single `if` I am stating that. It's a lot harder to sneak an operation inside of there where it shouldn't be.

I will always favor clear communication of my intention over someone's stupid assertion that it "doesn't work in all languages". Guess what... `throw` doesn't work in all languages either, does that mean I shouldn't use it when coding in C# or Java and should instead rely on return values to signal when there was a problem?

All that said, it's a lot more readable to invert it and just return out of the method if either is *not* satisfied as STW says in their answer.

Comment: More than two conditions might warrant their own function which return a null.

Answer (score 3):

In this instance your two clauses are directly related, so the 2nd form is preferable.

If they weren't related (e.g. a series of guard clauses on different conditions) then I'd prefer the 1st form (or I'd refactor out a method with a name which represents what the compound condition actually represents).

Answer (score 1):

If you work in Delphi, the first way is, in general, safer. (For the given example, there's not much to gain from using nested ifs.)

Delphi allows you to specify whether or not boolean expressions evaluate or "short circuit", through compiler switches. Doing way #1 (nested ifs) allows you to ensure that the second clause executes if and only if (and strictly *after*) the first clause evaluates to true.

Comment: In 23 years of Delphi development I have **never** changed the "Complete boolean eval" option. If I was shipping code elsewhere I would put {$BOOLEVAL OFF} or {$B-} in the unit.

Comment: Me neither. I also always use range checking too... but other people don't. And it _shouldn't_ make a difference except perhaps from a performance perspective becuase you _shouldn't_ be using side effects in functions used in boolean expressions. I'm sure someone out there does, though!

Comment: @Gerry: Agreed.  The only reason you could possibly want full evaluation is side effects--and side effects in a conditional are a bad idea!

Comment: Just re-read my comment 23 years should be 13! I don't have a Tardis

Answer (score 1):

The second style can backfire in VBA since if the first test is if the object generated, it will still do the second test and error out.  I've just got in the habit in VBA when dealing with object verification to always use the first method.

Comment: That's because VBA is a terrible language

Comment: @Falmarri, it has some terrible things about it (and some good things).  I would fix a lot of things if I had my druthers.

Comment: The lack of short-circuit Boolean evaluation is more of a legacy thing than anything. No idea why they didn't start out with it. The VB.NET "fix" of OrElse and AndAlso is kinda annoying, but probably the only option to deal with it without breaking backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

The second form is more readable, especially if you are using {} blocks around each clause, because the first form will lead to nested {} blocks and multiple levels of indentation, which can be a pain to read (you have to count indentation spaces to figure out where each block ends).

Answer (score 0):

I find them both readable, and I do not accept the argument that you should worry about code maintainability if you were to switch languages.

In some languages the second option performs better so it would be the clear choice then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with you; I do it the second way.  To me, it's logically clearer.  The concern that some languages will execute the second part even if the first evaluates to false seems a tad silly to me, as I have never in my life written a program that ran in "some languages"; my code always seems to exist in a specific language, which either can handle that construction or can't.  (And if I'm not sure whether the specific language can handle it, that's something I really need to learn, isn't it.)

In my mind, the hazard with the first way of doing it is that it leaves me vulnerable to accidentally putting in code outside of that nested `if` block when I didn't mean to.  Which, admittedly, is hardly a huge concern, but it seems more reasonable than fretting over whether my code is language agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the second option, because it is more readable.

If the logic you're implementing is more complex (checking that a string is not null and not empty is just an example), then you can make a useful refactoring: extract a boolean function.  I'm with @mipadi on the "Code Complete" remark ("it doesn't matter if all languages do that...")  If the reader of your code isn't interested in looking inside the extracted function, then the order in which boolean operands are evaluated becomes a moot question to them.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((byteArrayVariable != null)
 && (byteArrayVariable.Length != 0)) {
    //Do something with byteArrayVariable
```

but that's basically the second option.